# PHP: Substr() returns empty string

Tags: php, substr

I want to get the first letters of a string, but every time its giving me a empty result. The string is following.

```
080521234567890
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
        if ($_GET['test1']) 
        {
            echo "<table border =0>";
            $parsing = "080521234567890";
            echo "<tr>";
            if ($p1 = substr($parsing,0,1))    
                {
                    echo "<td><strong>Version Format n1</strong></td>";
                    echo "<td>: $p1</td"; 
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        }
    ?>
```

In the line **echo ": $p1</td";**  return empty value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux9Bj.png)

Comment: TD tag is not closed, correctly.

Comment: The first number is 0, so it evaluates to false and does not enter your `if` block.

Comment: The real question is: What do you think that that `if($p1...)` is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue doesn't come from the substring function, but from your condition.

This code is working fine :

```
<?php

    echo "<table border =0>";

        $parsing = "080521234567890";

        echo "<tr>";

            $p1 = substr($parsing,0,1);  

            echo "<td><strong>Version Format n1</strong></td>";
            echo "<td>: $p1</td>"; //returns 0

        echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    
?>
```

Referring to yours, your if statement uses the assignment operator (=) instead of comparison (==) and returns 0 because it is the first character of your string *$parsing*. So you do not execute statements inside your condition block.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to compare, you need to update your condition, instead of `$p1 = substr($parsing,0,1)`, you need to make `$p1 == substr($parsing,0,1)`, and if you want strict comparison, you can use `$p1 === substr($parsing,0,1)` as well.

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['test1']) 
    {
        echo "<table border =0>";
        $parsing = "080521234567890";
        echo "<tr>";
//single = will assign value and will always be true
        if ($p1 == substr($parsing,0,1))    
            {
                echo "<td><strong>Version Format n1</strong></td>";
                echo "<td>: $p1</td"; 
            }
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Else, if you are trying to assign value, you need to get rid of `if block` and do something like this

```
$p1 = substr($parsing,0,1));    
echo "<td><strong>Version Format n1</strong></td>";
echo "<td>: $p1</td";
```

Comment: They're trying to assign the return value of `substr` to $p1, not compare it. In your code, `$p1` has not been defined.